# How to perform checks on data type construction

Tags: haskell

For a data type constructor, is there any way to limit the creation of the "object" (I don't know the proper term) based on criteria other than the types of the arguments to the constructor?

For instance:

```
data UInt = UInt Int --the int must be >= 0
```

Truly, I would like to create a data type for rectangular multidimensional lists (in which all the sublists have the same length). Would a class or some other technique be better suited for this?

Comment: You are going to *love* the paper ["Manufacturing Datatypes"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.2207) by Ralf Hinze. The first two sentences of the abstract are "This paper describes a general framework for designing purely functional datatypes that automatically satisfy given size or structural constraints. Using the framework we develop implementations of different matrix types.".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to enforce what values a user passes to a constructor.

However, there is a common practice in the community and standard library of creating *smart constructors*.  You see these in modules like `Data.Map`, `Data.Ratio`, and many more.  Simply put, you don't export the constructor itself, just the type, and you export a function which vets the arguments:

```
module UInt
    ( UInt
    , uint
    ) where

data UInt = UInt Int

uint :: Int -> Maybe UInt
uint x | x >= 0 = Just (UInt x)
       | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the line `( UInt` import only the data type `UInt` and not the constructor `UInt`?

Comment: @MarkAnastos it only exports the type, allowing other modules to import it. You would have to specify it as UInt(UInt) or UInt(..) to export the specific constructor or all constructors respectively.